# Hyper reference link for roman numbered pages in latex

Tags: pdflatex, tableofcontents, hyperref

I have an article class document in latex with roman numbers for abstract, toc, tables and figures. In the Table of contents the list appears correctly with correct numbering as well. But the hyperlink for roman numbers are not working. If I click on any of them they all lead to title page, i.e page 0.

Can someone help me with the code which properly links to the roman numbered pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{abstract}
   some text here
\end{abstract}

    \renewcommand\listtablename{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
    \cleardoublepage

    % abbreviations:
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbreviations}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
    \cleardoublepage

    \renewcommand\listtablename{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \cleardoublepage

    \renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
    \clearpage

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! You also need package `glossaries` to compile. After that, it all seems regular to me: links work correctly in the titles in the table contents, not in page numbers...

Comment: Hi,I had included that package already ! i posted the answer which worked out for me.Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed it with below changes :

I moved the \renew commands to before \begin{document} and then added \phantomsection before each of \listoffigures and \listoftables